# How to pass arguments at runtime which can be picked by html code

Tags: html

I want a parameter in html code to be dynamic which is passed while the code. For eg if I run eg.html?link=https://google.com then the html code should be able to parse google.com and be able to open it. If I run eg.html?link=https://gmail.com, then gmail should open.

Answer (score 0):

HTML alone cannot do that. In order to dynamically change the content of the HTML file, you will need some server-side processing using a language such as PHP, Python, or Node.js.